# using NSString + stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:

Tags: iphone, encoding, nsstring

I've got problem with use + stringWithContentsOfFile:usedEncoding:error:

My problem in usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding *)enc
I don't know how can i set pointer to encoding. If i make it - programm is fail.

For example, in similar function we have encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc - without pointer!

I want loading file (file has encoding ISOLatin1) in NSString and use NSString as UTF8String.

how can i make it ?

thanks.

Comment: usedEncoding is a return value. From the documentation:
> enc
> Upon return, if the file is read successfully, contains the
> encoding used to interpret the file at path.

Comment: Sorry about that, was sure markup worked in the comment field as well.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSError* error;
NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:myFilePath usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
```

Comment: Except, the first variable type is spelled NSStringEncoding (no 'e')